# Disable full window drag

Tags: java, macos, transparency, drag

when I use `AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, false);` to make my JFrames' background transparent, you can change the location of my JFrame by dragging it anywhere in the window. My problem is, that I have Objects I want to use for drag and drop on this Frame, but when the JFrame moves when I try to drag an object its impossible to drop it anywhere else.
Is there any way to solve this problem?

By the way, I am on Mac using Mac OS 10.6.6

Thanks for your help!

Comment: "Is there any way to solve this problem?"  What problem exactly?

Comment: I have draggable object on this JFrame. Buth when the JFrames moves when I try to drag these objects its impossible to drop these objects anywhere else

Answer (score 6):

Sorry for the my bad english.
Try this:

```
setUndecorated(true); 
AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, false); 
getRootPane().putClientProperty("apple.awt.draggableWindowBackground", Boolean.FALSE);
```

By default the setWindowOpaque function set this client property as true. But  this client property makes every component within your window draggable.

Now you have to make the drag code by yourself.

Comment: Why `Boolean.FALSE` as opposed to `false`?

Answer (score 0):

You should test that on windows as I think that's a mac feature. You can, in general click anywhere in the frame to drag an app about. What's your target deployment platform?
Maybe you can put another panel in it and set that to non-opague. maybe this will help?

Comment: if it is completely transparent (with no panel) you cannot drag it. But when there is a panel in it (not completely transparent) you can drag it. Yes, thats a mac "feature"/bug.

Comment: I *wish* that was a Mac feature, because I can't figure out how to make my toolbars behave like that.