# Making JFrame transparent breaks scrolling on Mac

Tags: java, macos, swing, scroll, transparent

I have a transparent undecorated `JFrame` that I set using `AWTUtilities.setWindowOpaque(this, false)`.  On the `JFrame`, I have a scrollpane; it works perfectly on Windows. On the Mac, the whole `JFrame` is draggable; so when I try to scroll through the scrollpane by clicking and holding the mouse on the scrollbar, the entire frame moves instead of the scrollbar thumb.  I also tried to use `setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0))` instead of `setWindowOpaque()`, but it has the same problem.  Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: What is your JRE version, is it 1.7 ?

Comment: You might try setting the background to almost-transparent, e.g. Color(0,0,0,10) or so (not certain of the exact threshold).

Comment: It seems like any kind of transparency breaks it.  I tried Color(0,0,0,.99f) and it doesn't work.

Comment: @user1309036 : So sorry, can not test that, since I am using Windows :-(

Comment: It's a usability feature for undecorated frames, which would otherwise be immoveable. See also this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2166500/230513).

Comment: If you _don't_ click, does the mouse wheel scroll the content?

Comment: Do you have some sample code I can try?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in [this similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6139080/1539697), try:

```
getRootPane().putClientProperty("apple.awt.draggableWindowBackground", Boolean.FALSE);
```

If you choose to use this, the scrollbar will be usable and the window won't drag. However, you may be stuck with an immovable window, unless you add a `MouseMotionListener` and move the window around in the `mouseDragged()` method using a call like `frame.setLocation()`.

Instead, you might be able to force the user to click on the scrollbar's arrow buttons, rather than drag the scrollbar itself... But that's not the most user-friendly idea I've ever seen.